# How to make a container class than is able to call all class functions and apply them on all contained objects?

Tags: matlab, oop

I have a class 'classB' that contains multiple objects of classA as a property. classB contains the same methods as classA but applies them on all ClassA objects it contains. Is there a way to do this in a single classB function instead of adding them all with a for loop?

```
classdef ClassB
    properties
         ClassAObj{1:3} %cell containing multiple class A objects
    end
    methods
        function function1(ClassB)
             for k = 1:numel(ClassAObj)
                 obj.ClassAObj{k}.function1 
             end
        end
        function function2(ClassB)
             for k = 1:numel(ClassAObj)
                 obj.ClassAObj{k}.function2 
             end
        end
        function...        
    end
end


classdef ClassA
    methods
        function1
        function2
        function...
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `cellfun`? Note that `obj.ClassAObj{k}.function1` is the same as `function1(obj.ClassAObj{k})`. You can do `cellfun(@function1,obj.ClassAObj)`, maybe with some parameter specifying you don't expect and output.

Comment: You really put me in the right direction. Your solution works for me but i discovered that I also can create an array of ClassA objects and apply arrayfun on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the following line will apply the given function to all objects in obj.ClassAObj, where obj is a classB object.

```
obj.SuperFunction(@function1)


classdef ClassB
    properties
        ClassAObj{1:3} %cell containing multiple class A objects
    end
    methods
        function obj = ClassB
            %constructor loading ClassA objects
            ...
        end
        function Superfunction(obj,ClassAfunctionName)
            cellfun(ClassAfunctionName,obj.ClassAObj)                 
        end      
    end
end
```